# Assign a Value when two checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, adobe

I am trying to come up with a JS for a memory test. In a series of 6 tries, Once the tester selects two consecutive checkboxes, I want to assign a Value of "1" to a specific field.

To simplify:
if checkbox1 && checkbox2 are checked, then assign value of 1 
if checkbox2 && checkbox3 are checked, then assign value of 1 just to checkbox2 and checkbox3

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have tried anything, please post your code snippet here, so we can improve it.

Comment: {
var total = 0;
if ((this.getField("checkbox1").valueAsString) && ((this.getField(checkbox2).valueAsString)!="Off") total+=1;
event.value = total;
}

Comment: So e.g if user checked checkbox1 then I want x = 0, i if both then for it to display the price that is determined the value "1" in both fields.